# How do I access the id attribute of an option element from the source component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to access the `id` attribute of `HTMLOptionElement` when a user makes their selection, but it always returns `0` instead of the actual `id` I passed (such as `1` or `2`).
the `select tag`:

```
<div class="col-8">
        <select (change)="processSelection($event)" #selectedCategory class="custom-select">
            <option value ="" class="text-center">Select</option>
            <option [ngValue]="category"class="text-center"  
             *ngFor="let category of categoryNameAndId" [attr.id]="[category.id]">
                {{category.name}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

the source component:

```
processSelection(event:Event){
   const target  = event.target as HTMLOptionElement;
   const selected = target.value() //works very well
   const id = +target.id //doesn't return desired result
  // const id = Number(target.getAttribute('id'); //doesn't work either
   console.log("id is "+id);

  }
```

But if I implemented something like this `<div>{{category.id}}</div>` I got the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change to this to get the correct item to get the Id:

```
const id = this.categoryNameAndId.find(category => category.name === selected)?.id;
```

Or something like this:

```
processSelection(event:Event){
   const selectedCategory = this.categoryNameAndId.find(category => category.name === event.target.value);
   const selected = selectedCategory?.name;
   const id = selectedCategory?.id;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `const selectedCategory = this.categoryNameAndId.find(category=>category.name===event.target.value)`